# Return an empty Observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

The function `more()` is supposed to return an `Observable` from a get request

```ts
export class Collection {
  public more = (): Observable<Response> => {
    if (this.hasMore()) {
      return this.fetch();
    } else {
      // return empty observable
    }
  };

  private fetch = (): Observable<Response> => {
    return this.http.get("some-url").map((res) => {
      return res.json();
    });
  };
}
```

In this case I can only do a request if `hasMore()` is true, else I get an error on `subscribe()` function `subscribe is not defined`, how can I return an empty Observable?

```ts
this.collection.more().subscribe(
  (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since all the answers are outdated, I will post the up to date answer here

In RXJS >= 6

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs'
return EMPTY;
```

Answer (score 200):

With the new syntax of RxJS 5.5+, this becomes as the following:

```
// RxJS 6
import { EMPTY, empty, of } from "rxjs";

// rxjs 5.5+ (<6)
import { empty } from "rxjs/observable/empty";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";

empty(); // deprecated use EMPTY
EMPTY;
of({});
```

Just one thing to keep in mind, `EMPTY` completes the observable, so it won't trigger `next` in your stream, but only completes. So if you have, for instance, `tap`, they might not get trigger as you wish (see an example below).

Whereas `of({})` creates an `Observable` and emits next with a value of `{}` and then it completes the `Observable`.

E.g.:

```
EMPTY.pipe(
    tap(() => console.warn("i will not reach here, as i am complete"))
).subscribe();

of({}).pipe(
    tap(() => console.warn("i will reach here and complete"))
).subscribe();
```

Comment: [You can also just do `of()` I believe](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/test-file/spec-js/observables/of-spec.js.html#lineNumber41)

Comment: `of('foo')` does emit and complete the observable immediately. https://rxviz.com/v/0oqMVW1o

Comment: @SimplGy yes you are correct, my bad for using `take(1)` removed for a better answer.

@MatthijsWessels, yes and no, just tested this now and if you do `of()` will return a complete observable without emitting `next`

Comment: empty is now deprecated, use EMPTY instead (used as a constant instead of as a method, see answer by Simon_Weaver).

Comment: Please bear in mind, of() does not emit any value. If you want one, you should provide any value, even undefined or null is ok for that: of(null) emits the value (and processes with tap/subscribe methods), while of() does not.

Comment: Be wary of `EMPTY`s relationship with `.subscribe()`. For example, `EMPTY.subscribe(() => {console.log('test');})` probably doesn't do what you think it does. More info here https://blog.novanet.no/rxjs-getting-fooled-by-empty-observables/

Answer (score 151):

For typescript you can specify generic param of your empty observable like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty' 

Observable.empty<Response>();
```

Comment: This should now be `import "EmptyObservable" from "rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable";`, then `new EmptyObservable<Response>();`.

Answer (score 63):

#### RxJS6 (without compatibility package installed)

There's now an `EMPTY` constant and an `empty` function.

```
  import { Observable, empty, EMPTY, of } from 'rxjs';

  //This is now deprecated
  var delay = empty().pipe(delay(1000));     
  var delay2 = EMPTY.pipe(delay(1000));
```

`Observable.empty()` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Update guide: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: If you have a conflict such as an `empty()` function already you can say `import { empty as rxEmpty }` or `import { empty as _empty }` and then do `rxEmpty()` or `_empty()`. Of course that's a pretty non standard thing to do and I'm not actually recommending it, but I'm sure I'm not the only one that was surprised RxJS thinks it is worthy of importing functions like `of` and `empty` into my namespace!

Comment: careful if using Angular because there's also `import { EMPTY } from "@angular/core/src/render3/definition";` which is completely not what you want. So if you're getting odd errors make sure you're not importing that by mistake.

Comment: `Observable.empty()` actually [still exists](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ffb4b0b52f8f8402ddd354169be285c78fcf9988/src/internal/observable/empty.ts#L62) but it's deprecated in favor of `EMPTY`.

Comment: Be wary of `EMPTY`s relationship with `.subscribe()`. For example, `EMPTY.subscribe(() => {console.log('test');})` probably doesn't do what you think it does. More info here https://blog.novanet.no/rxjs-getting-fooled-by-empty-observables/

Answer (score 51):

**Several ways to create an Empty Observable:**

They just differ on how you are going to use it further (what events it will emit after: `next`, `complete` or `do nothing`) e.g.:

- *`Observable.never()`* - emits no events and never ends.
- *`Observable.empty()`* - emits only **`complete`**.
- *`Observable.of({})`* - emits both **`next`** and **`complete`** (Empty object literal passed as an example).

Use it on your exact needs)

Answer (score 42):

In my case with Angular2 and rxjs, it worked with:

```
import {EmptyObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable';
...
return new EmptyObservable();
...
```

Comment: include it with `import {EmptyObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable';`

Comment: getting error like this, DO I need to configure anything in system-config ?
    Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9190/node_modules/rxjs/Observable/EmptyObservable.js
 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9190/node_modules/rxjs/Observable/EmptyObservable.js

Answer (score 29):

Yes, there is am [Empty](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/empty.md) operator

```
Rx.Observable.empty();
```

For typescript, you can use `from`:

```
Rx.Observable<Response>.from([])
```

Comment: I'm getting `Rx.Observable<{}>` is not assignable to `Observable<Response>`, I tried to `Rx.Observable<Response>.empty()` but it didn't work

Comment: I changed the return type to `Observable<any>` and it worked, thanks mate.

Comment: It should be `Rx.Observable.from([])` without `<Response>`. Otherwise getting an error "expression expected".

Comment: You can also use `Rx.Observable.of([])`.

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy I am not sure this is equivalent. In `Observable.of([])`, there is one value emitted ( `[]`) and then the stream completes. With `Observable.from([])`, no value is emitted, the stream completes immediately.

Comment: The documentation states that it's better to use the `import {EMPTY} from 'rxjs'` (better than the `empty()` method). I assume that it's a memory thing (i.e. reusing the same empty values is better than creating multiple empty objects)

Answer (score 19):

You can return Observable.of(empty_variable), for example

```
Observable.of('');

// or
Observable.of({});

// etc
```

Answer (score 5):

Differents way to  return empty observable :

1. Observable.from({});
2. Observable.of({});
3. EMPTY

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/empty

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try `ignoreElements()` as well

Answer (score 2):

**RxJS 6**

you can use also from function like below:

```
return from<string>([""]);
```

after import:

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: This will create an Observable that will provide one element (an empty string), so it doesn't look like a proper answer to this specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Came here with a similar question, the above didn't work for me in: `"rxjs": "^6.0.0"`, in order to generate an observable that emits no data I needed to do:

```
import {Observable,empty} from 'rxjs';
class ActivatedRouteStub {
  params: Observable<any> = empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export class Collection{
public more (): Observable<Response> {
   if (this.hasMore()) {
     return this.fetch();
   }
   else{
     return this.returnEmpty(); 
   }            
  }
public returnEmpty(): any {
    let subscription = source.subscribe(
      function (x) {
       console.log('Next: %s', x);
    },
    function (err) {
       console.log('Error: %s', err);
    },
    function () {
       console.log('Completed');
    });
    }
  }
let source = Observable.empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the empty observable with all different ways but challenge is to to return it with the expected type -
Here is the way to create a empty observable with type -

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
return next.handle(this.setHeaders(req))
            .pipe(
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // you write your logic and return empty response if required
        return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>();
            }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is another: `EMPTY` const

Replaced with the EMPTY constant or scheduled (e.g. scheduled([], scheduler)). Will be removed in v8. (got this form phpstorm hint)