# how to return an empty observable

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable

according to this answer [How to return an empty observable in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548407/how-to-return-an-empty-observable-in-rxjs) i have tried all of it but it did not work for me

here is my code

```
post(url):Observalbe<any>{
   if(this.holder.nullConnection()){ //checking internet connection
      //return empty observalbe
      return Observable.empty() ;
    }else{
      return this.http.post(this.configurator.restServerBaseUrl+url,data)
      .map((result:Response)=> {
        return result.json()
      })
    }
}
```

i have tried almost all the answers as per the stack question you can see above any help to return an empty obserable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return an empty observable in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548407/how-to-return-an-empty-observable-in-rxjs)

Comment: please read my question i have mentioned your question and asked my question diff from yours  @murhaf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Observable.of()` should work for your case:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// or import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

return Observable.of();
```

or

```
import {EmptyObservable} from 'rxjs/EmptyObservable';

return new EmptyObservable();
```

Comment: i tried both as i am using visual studio and my editor is showing error on `of()` do we have to import anything like EmptyObservable

Comment: as you can see my else part is working fine only i am struggling to retrun an empty observable

Comment: u have to import the of operator

Comment: it is saying that cannot find name of() like that

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer [ts] Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. this is the error

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 you can return empty observable by using this :

```
import {EmptyObservable} from 'rxjs/EmptyObservable';
    return new EmptyObservable();
```

Comment: For me; `import {EmptyObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable';`