# How to correctly return a void Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular 4 application, I have a method that have to return an `Observable`. This method has 3 conditions. First and second conditions make a get call, but the third condition does nothing and in this case I have to return an `Observable` as well, because this method is the first part of a `.flatmap` operator. So to chain the second part of the `.flatmap` operator, I need an `Observable` from the first part.

I've tried `return new Observable<void>();`, but I've got an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

This is the initial method that calls a service to load the data.

```
loadModelData() {
      this.customerService.getModelDetail(this.code)
        .subscribe(response => {
          this.selected = response.body as Customer;
        });
    }
  }
```

This is the service method that have to chain 2 calls.

```
getModelDetail(code) {

    const params = new HttpParams().set('projection', 'withBalance');

    return this.endPointUrlService.loadMaps(this.entityLink)

      .flatMap((res) => {
        return this.http.get(this.endPointUrlService.cutLinks(
          this.endPointUrlService.map.get('customers')) + '/' + code, {observe: 'response', params: params})
          .map((response) => <any>response);
      })
  }
```

And this is the methods from a support service. `checkIfMapIsReady()` is a method that returns a `void` `Observable` in the third case:

```
  loadMaps(entityLink: EntityLink[]): Observable<void> {
    console.log(entityLink);

    for (const i in entityLink) {
      if (entityLink.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      return this.checkIfMapIsReady(entityLink[i].name, entityLink[i].searchMap, entityLink[i].endPoints[0])
      }
    }
  }


  public checkIfMapIsReady(modelName: string, mapName: string, endPoints: string) {

    if (this.map.get(modelName) === undefined) {
      console.log('endpoint url service All maps undefined ' + modelName);
      return this.getLinks(modelName, this.mapNames.get(mapName), false)
    } else {
      console.log('endpoint url service Populate only ' + mapName);
      if (this.mapNames.get(mapName).get(endPoints) === undefined) {
      return  this.getLinks(modelName, this.mapNames.get(mapName), true)
      } else {
        return new Observable<void>();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return an empty Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548407/return-an-empty-observable)

Answer (score 104):

`return of();` doesn't create a stream.

Whereas

`return of(void 0);`

does.

if you are mocking and need to return a stream of `void`. Like my life. [Sad Panda]

Comment: `void 0` is the shortest way to write `undefined`

Answer (score 24):

An observable that matches `Observable<void>` type is

```
Observable.of();
```

It results in complete observable with no values and is similar to `Observable.empty()`.

While

```
new Observable<void>();
```

is incorrect because it lacks subscribe function argument. It could be instead:

```
new Observable<void>(observer => observer.complete());
```

Comment: If I return an undefined value do I have a problem with the flat map or subscribe?

Comment: The post answers the question directly. This is how `void` observable is returned. You possibly will have problem with flatMap, but this means that `Observable<void>` type is wrong. The way it should be done depends on how getModelDetail is supposed to work in your case. It can be `return Observable.empty()` or something else.

Comment: `Observable.of()` does not emit a single undefined, it does not emit anything. For that you want `Observable.of(undefined)`.

Comment: Neither of the solutions proposed by @EstusFlask works, Richard consider writing your own answer please.

Comment: @JacopoLanzoni It works. If it doesn't work as you expect, this means that your expectations differ from what the answer suggests. As it was said, Observable.of() and Observable.of(undefined) are different things.

Answer (score 16):

You can also try:

```
return of(null);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works the same in my tests as `return of(void)`
Thanks for this *thumbs_up

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps `Observable.empty()` is a better options, since it does not emit any values, the downstream operators can't have a problem with what it returns!

Note, downstream `flatMap(res => ...)` and `subscribe()` will not trigger.
Since you're not using `res`, I presume this is the desired effect?

For good measure, make the return type `Observable<any>`.

I ***think*** this below is logically equivalent to the posted `checkIfMapIsReady()`,

```js
public checkIfMapIsReady(modelName: string, mapName: string, endPoints: string) {

  const map = this.map.get(modelName);
  const name = this.mapNames.get(mapName);
  const endPointCheck = name ? name.get(endPoints) : null;

  const links = !endPointCheck 
    ? this.getLinks(modelName, name, !!map)     // !! gives boolean true or false
    : Observable.empty();

  const msg = !map 
    ? 'endpoint url service All maps undefined ' + modelName
    : 'endpoint url service Populate only ' + mapName
  console.log(msg);    

  return links;
);
```

Comment: If I return `Observable.empty()` in my code instead of `Observable<void>()` I have `The type argument for type parameter 'T' canno
t be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'void' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate '{}'.`

Comment: For good measure, make the return type Observable<any>. - that's referring to the return type in the method signature. Using 'any' as a type stops Typescript complaining about the type, useful when you might want to return one of two types (as you are).

Comment: if I change `return new Observable<void>()` I have a problem in the first part of flatmap: `Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<void>'.` for every observable I try to return except void

Comment: I noted that you weren't using the `res` parameter passed into `flatMap`. If that is indeed the case, you may consider changing the return to `Observable<boolean>` (with appropriate logic changes), instead of return links or Observable<any>.

Comment: Re your last comment, I'm suggesting you ***also*** change the ***other*** `Observable<void>` to `Observable<any>`. Apologies if you have already changed them **both**.

Comment: In my code I only need to chain 2 get call,so I use flatmap, but I don't need to use the first  response in the second get call. The method getLinks return an observable void and I can't change it

Comment: Ok, getLinks returns observable void - I assumed it returned observable of links. So, I presume you need to wait for getLinks to finish. Let me add another version to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158305/discussion-between-richard-matsen-and-alessandro).

Comment: [`Observable.empty()` is no longer valid. You should return `EMPTY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47600725/542251)

Answer (score 2):

For RxJS 6.x, you need to import it like this:

`import { of } from 'rxjs';`

And then just use

`return of();`

As you can see: without any parameter means an observable that matches `Observable<void>`.

Comment: as said above, `of()` doesn't fire but completes, that might not be the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bahaviour observables. they have an initial value, and when you subscribe to them, the subscription works on that initial value. so let's say you wanna operate on a new instance of Customer if the third condition was true, so you do this:

`

```
let customer = new Customer();
let subj = new BehaviorSubject<Customer>(customer);
....
if(thirdcondition){
  return subj;
}
```

`

so now when you call subscribe() on this method, and that last block is executed, you have what you wanted.
you can change `new customer()` to anything you want by default.

Comment: But that `BehaviourSubject` would never complete, no? Wouldn't that create a dangling/lost subscription?

Comment: It's been years since I've written Angular code. Sorry but I do not remember