# Using typescript, what is a good Observable type to best represent a HTTP response with no content?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

Using typescript, Angular 6+ and rxjs, how to best represent to the caller that an HTTP response content is empty (Content-Length=0)?

Without specifying types in the method call (`get`, `post`, etc.), an `Observable<Object>` is returned, which is misleading regarding the response content, as one can be tempted to use the given object:

```js
let response: Observable<Object> = httpClient.post('...');
response.subscribe(o => ...);
```

In this case, `o` is always null, but this is not explicit nor checked by the compiler.

A better solution would be to return `Observable<null>` but I find the semantic to be ambiguous, as null could also refer to a null data (eg, a customer without phone number would have a phoneNumber property set to null).

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548407/how-to-return-an-empty-observable-in-rxjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Observable.empty()`

or

`empty()` if you have imported from `rxjs`

Comment: It's not perfect since it requires to change the subscribe method (to use the `complete` callback instead of `next`). But I agree that `empty` is the best operator to convey the meaning of a _completed_ HTTP request with _empty_ content.

Comment: @Clément You can use `subscribe({ complete: () => ... })`

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for actually exist and its correct type is `Observable<void>`. Like you said `null` is a regular value that can be produced by any Observable. In RxJS 6 this is represented by `empty()` which is like any other Observable but it doesn't emit any `next` value and just sends the `complete` signal.

```
import { empty, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

empty().subscribe(...) // will receive just the `complete` notification

// or you can use EMPTY

EMPTY.subscribe(...)
```

By the way you can also turn any Observable into `Observable<void>` using the `ignoreElements()` operator.

There're also `never()` and `NEVER` Observables but don't mistake them for `empty()` because these don't emit anything (not even the `complete` notification).

Comment: `Observable<void>` is technically working but its semantic is hard to reason about: does it emit something? in what sense is the value "void"? `empty()` is good but like I said to @Sunil Singh, its too bad that the use of the subscribe method changes depending on whether there is a content or not (using sometimes `next` and sometimes `complete`).

Comment: Well, it has to change. How would you distinguish a valid value from a situation where you don't want to emit anything? That's what `complete` and `error` notifications are for. Of course you can use `null` but it seems like you wanted to avoid this. The `void` type is a TypeScript type that represents nothing (like `NULL` in a database). Then `Observable<T>` is an Observable that emits `next` items of type `T`. So `Observable<void>` is an Observable that emits nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method for send a request as `Observable` like:

```
 // Add a new comment
    addComment (body: Object): Observable<Comment[]> {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl, body, options) // ...using post request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
    }   

    // Update a comment
    updateComment (body: Object): Observable<Comment[]> {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        return this.http.put(`${this.commentsUrl}/${body['id']}`, body, options) // ...using put request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
    }   

    // Delete a comment
    removeComment (id:string): Observable<Comment[]> {
        return this.http.delete(`${this.commentsUrl}/${id}`) // ...using put request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
    }
```

Or simply use of `HttpClient` like:

```
getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
}

    addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
           catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
         );
    }
```