# How to push the empty JSON data to an array field which is type of Observable<any[]> angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have a variable like,

```
public categories: Observable<any[]>;
```

So after the service call, the returned data of service call will push an array of JSON data to the field which I mentioned above.

After that, I need to push an empty JSON data to that field. As it is a type of Observable, I can't just directly use **.push**

**Is there any solution to push the empty JSON data to an array which is type of Observable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to import latest `EmptyObservable` of **rxjs**, that will do the trick in your case.

```
import {EmptyObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable';

public categories: Observable<any[]>;

//just assign this to your variable
this.categories = new EmptyObservable();
```

for more info have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39941749/9764133)

Comment: Perfect! Working...Thank you

Comment: glad to help you... :)