# Why`of()` observable is not executing next()?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this situation:

```
 this._userService
            .create(user)
            .pipe(
                switchMap(res => {
                    if (this.accountStore.accounts.length > 0) {
                        return this._accountsService.manageAccounts(
                            accounts,
                            res.idUser
                        );
                    } else return of();
                })
            )
            .subscribe(
                _ => {
                    this._router.navigate(["/app/main/user/"]);
                },
                () => (this.saving = false)
            );
```

if the accounts are higher then 0, it works ok. But if it goes to the else block, the `return of()` doesn't execute the next() to navigate to the user route;

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you don't pass arguments to `of` there is nothing to emit.

Comment: but I just would like to execute the next function without any emitted value

Comment: You can't. You might want to use a complete handler instead, if you're not using the value.

Comment: You can also use `of(undefined)` or `of(void 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a value into `of` to execute next operator or subscriber. In this case I just pass `null` as `of(null)`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032365/10747134) but different because of versions, you need to use the `of({}).pipe(take(1))` to create an empty object observable and call next.

For your code:

```
...
} else return of({}).pipe(take(1));
...
```

Comment: but this does not emit any value at all, so still cannot hit else branch

Comment: Woops, great catch. Updating

Answer (score 0):

**Is cleaner if you use the creational operator [`EMPTY`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/empty.html)**

The documentation says:

> Observable that immediately completes.
>
> Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits a complete notification.

---

Example:

```js
// RxJS v6+
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

//output: 'Complete!'
const subscribe = EMPTY.subscribe({
  next: () => console.log('Next'),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete!')
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-aqfpkq?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100)