# what types do "toPromise()" exist on in order to create mock?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, return

I have code I cannot edit and code I can.

the code I can't edit is the following :

```
this.getLogs()
    .toPromise()
    .then((resp: any) => ({
      data: resp['results'],
      totalCount: resp['count']
}));
```

the code I can edit is the following.

```
  private getLogs() {
    if (this.id) { // I added this
      params = {};
      params['log_id'] = this.id;
      const url = `${AppGlobal.API_URL}${thislogsUrl}`;
      return this.http.post(
        url,
        params,
        this.authService.getRequestOptions()
      ).pipe(catchError(error => this.handleError(error)));
    } else {  // I added this
      return <---- What do I put here????
    }
  }
```

I can't for the all the googling in the world find what I am supposed to put on that return that would make the code I can't edit happy.

whatever I return must have the type "toPromise()". but I don't actually want to make an api call in that case (the case where I'm missing the parameter)

I've tried :

1. return new Observable(string ).delay(500);
2. return new Promise(null);
3. return Rx.Observable.of('o').delay(500);
4. not returning

but none of these are even correct syntax on their own.

The bottom line is I don't want to get an error state. I want it to be silent in that case. preferably do nothing.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032365/10342976](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032365/10342976) I think this will help your case.

Comment: yeah that works. (the comment underneath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toPromise()` method exists on Observable class so you have to return an Observable. Since you need to turn it into Promise you can return for example `EMPTY` that will be turned into a Promise that resolves immediately with value `undefined`.

You can use eventually `of(undefined)` as well.

Comment: `empy()` is deprecated and is going to be replaced by `EMPTY` constant. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/empty.ts#L65

Comment: It depends on what RxJS version you're using. Since RxJS 5.5 the recommended way is using only pipable operators https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md. `EMPTY` is a constant, not a method as `empty()`. That's why it doesn't have any parenthesis.

Comment: could you give an example syntax? is it `new Observable(index/EMPTY)` ?

Comment: You import it with `import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';` and then use it like any other Observable: `EMPTY.pipe(...).subscribe()`.