# Non-completing observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Somewhere in my application, I have a function that must return an Observable. Most of the time, this works fine, but there is an instance where it's not really possible to provide a meaningful result. If this is the case, the caller won't do anything with the result either.

Because it doesn't really matter what the result is, I return `new Observable()` here. If I return nothing (like `return;`), I get an error so I must return an Observable.

The thing I'm worried about is making Observables like these that never complete. At the end of an Observable's lifespan, `subscriber.complete()` is used to indicate the Observable isn't going to do anything anymore. If I don't do that, will this result in any serious problems, like memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many types of Observable :

- finite (like Http requests)
- infinite

The type of infinite is allowing memory leak or some "bizarre" issues because depend on observable used like replay.

To return observable who complete() now without emit next() value :

```
return EMPTY;
```

If you need to pass through next() :

```
return of({});
```

[Return an empty Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548407/return-an-empty-observable)

My advice is to use a **takeUntil** in pipe to unsubscribe to avoid memory leak.

https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f

Answer (score 2):

There's an RxJS constant observable that completes immediately. It's called `EMPTY`

So just return `EMPTY`. It'll be semantically clearer too.